# Chart area exceeding series length

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts, kendo-ui

I pull data remotely to create a line chart. The chart spans time. So weekly, monthly, quarter, etc... Series shows digits representing dollar or percentage. Anyhow, problem I have is this. If a user wants to view data for current quarter and the date is the middle of the quarter, the anything after current date drops to zero. Is there a way to have the chart area show the defined time (weekly, current quarter, etc...) but then cut the series at current date? Even if the pulled remote data shows zero rather than null or anything like that? I cannot find examples or documentation for this and no luck so far. So am hoping someone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29) which allows to define "range" on axis.

ps. please recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, It sounds like something that should be handled on the back end, when you pull the data...if I understand the problem correctly.

It sounds like you are building the data series with zero values if there is no data - if you change that to populate with null values, or if you simply don't build the data series beyond the available data, your problem should go away.